# "Advise" vs. "advice"

Tags: orthography, se-ce

In what contexts are those two words used?

It's been a while since I've read the grammar books and I don't exactly remember the definitions of a few terms like adjective, so I would really appreciate it if the answers didn't leave it off by saying *x* is verb and *y* is adjective - I learn more by practical examples.

Please do mention similar words as well.

Comment: Related: [Can “advise” be used with the definition of “advice”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4934/), [“Defense” or “defence”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/), [License and licence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2882/), [Practise v. practice](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/), and [“Offense” vs. “offence”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16668/).

Comment: @RegDwight, ouch! How about merging them to one question with keywords that will find question searching with those words. They cover the same topic, right?

Comment: They cover very similar things, yes. But they are distinct enough. The questions are not *identical*, and the answers to them even less so. And the ultimate decision is with the community anyway. *I* can close everything as a dupe of [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/what-is-the-origin-of-zomg), throw away the key and go home. But that is not part of my job description. My job is to try to exert an influence using soft power aka related links.

Comment: @RegDwight, point taken, your efforts are much appreciated.

Comment: @RegDwightΒВB: Isn't this general reference? Unlike the other questions, there's no difference for *advi{s,c}e* between AmE and BrE, so there's nothing to say here beyond what's found by looking them up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Advise* is a verb, so it is used to indicate an action. So for instance:

> I advise you to do xyz.

*Advice* is a noun that derives from *advise*. So you would use it as the subject or the object of your sentence.

> - My advice is to do xyz.
> - The best advice I can give you is to do xyz.

Answer (score 7):

When you advise someone you are giving them advice.

More specifically, *advice* is a noun, that is, it is the thing that is being told to the person being advised.

*Advise* is the verb, or action, of giving someone advice.

Answer (score 5):

*Advice* is the actual content or helpful tip or whatever it was you gave the person:

> Their advice was helpful.
>
> I need some advice!

*Advise* is the action of helping someone:

> They advised me on writing a letter.
>
> Someone advise me!