# Difference in usage of "advise" and "advice"

Tags: differences, orthography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Advise” vs “advice”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17949/advise-vs-advice)

What is the correct usage of the words *advise* and *advice*?

Comment: Dictionaries generally include examples of the correct usage of words, and in order that we don't waste time reproducing that, it would be very helpful to state what you found and why that is inadequate. As it stands, your question is General Reference (as well as a duplicate).