# ZOMG -- I get the OMG part, but Z?

Tags: dialects, acronyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the origin of ZOMG?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/what-is-the-origin-of-zomg)

What ever does ZOMG mean? And where did it come from?

Answer (score 2):

It means the same thing as "OMG" -- that is, "Oh my God". Now it's often used to indicate a sarcastic or ironic usage of "omg".

[Some](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=zomg) suggest that it originated as a misspelling when users accidentally hit <kbd>Z</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> when typing "OMG", and the use of "ZOMG" became a way to mock Internet "newbies". On the other hand, many common Internet acronyms are evolve into ridiculous forms that are used sarcastically; for example, the simple "LOL" has turned into "lulz" and even "lollerskates", and "ROFL" has also manifested as "roflcopter".

Comment: A youth of my aquaintance refers to a decisive victory as "roflstomping".

Answer (score 1):

I always thought it invoked Zeus. As in Zounds!

Have internet acronyms such as these come to be accepted as part of the English Language? Sigh.