# What makes a word offensive?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, history, offensive-language

Whilst I was sat on the bus yesterday, I overheard a group of teenagers discussing various things. As per the usual social requirement at that age, every 5th word was an expletive. Not exactly the best *ambiance* for my journey home, but it got me thinking.

What specifically about the words "fuck", "shit", "cunt", etc. makes them so vulgar? Clearly they represent negative things in society, but what makes those particular words so important? Also, what makes words with similar pronunciation characteristics (e.g. "crap" and "damn") so much milder?

I'm aware that there will be some complex etymology of each, but what I'm really interested in is the structure and formation of the word itself. Why aren't "dotard" or "popinjay" considered to be curses, when "fuck" is? At certain times they held similar sentiments.

Is there something specific about how we pronounce them that makes them superior in situations where cursing is required? I'd also be interested to know how this works in other languages, too.

Comment: Words *convey* meaning; they are not one in the same. I might say total gibberish, but if my meaning is clear, then the lack of words doesn't even matter. Basically the reason they are offensive is because people get offended by them, and the rest remains a mystery of human psychology.

Comment: @tenfour - I understand that, but I'm talking more about the pronunciation and structure of the words themselves. There seem to be similarities across most swear words (even in different languages) such as the location of hard consonant sounds and number of syllables. I'm wondering why this is. The English Chicken's answer is very interesting in this regard.

Comment: This is more of a sociological issue than one of the English language. There are gestures and people and philosophies that people find just as offensive. Asking why certain "words" are also offensive doesn't change the scope and make it a question about English. The answers below would seem to bear that out (mostly historical/cultural references). You have a few answers I hope you find helpful, but I am going to close this as off topic.

Comment: Argh, [karabast](http://star-wars-canon.wikia.com/wiki/Karabast), this is a tough question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just whatever society decides is offensive.  Right now, culturally, sex is something of a taboo subject, and as such vulgar sexual words are usually offensive.

Hundreds of years ago, sex wasn't so taboo, and religious epithets were the main offensive language, such as "damn" or "God" or whatever, which is why you have ways around them from back then, like "Zounds" which means "God's wounds."  Any time you see the weird Z in old stuff like that that sounds very old fashioned and a little silly now, it's usually a stand in for "God" in order to get away from how offensive it was to take the Lord's name in vain when they came about.  Zounds is the only one I can really think of that's survived this long.

However, if you go back and read old stories from the 1300s or whenever, you'll find that they use the word "cunt" (or "cunte" or "coynte" or any of the other spellings they used then) a lot just in passing like it's nothing at all.  Same with a lot of our offensive language, at least with the older words.

Comment: So also "[zomg](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/what-is-the-origin-of-zomg)"? :P

Comment: That's a little too new for that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... I just posted it because you said "*Any time you see the weird Z in old stuff like that that sounds very old fashioned and a little silly now, it's usually a stand in for "God"* [...]"

Comment: Is there any credence to the idea that curse words tend to be one syllable because they're easy to utter? Or is it simply a coincidence?

Comment: @Alenanno, I meant old words, like hundreds of years old.  `zomg` is new, plus it's just a corruption of `omg` which already has God in it with the 'g' at the end.  `Zounds` dates back to the 1500s at least.  The Z = God equivalency isn't really around anymore.

Comment: @Polynomial, No idea.

Comment: @Phoenix It was kind of a joke, but well... :)

Comment: +1 for spot on about the shift from religion to sex as the primary source of taboo words. Chaucer was often derogatory and mocking about certain aspects of the Church, but he didn't really go in for "sacrilegious" profanity. He certainly had no such scruples when it came to vocabulary or subject matter concerning sex. Or indeed bodily functions, which are now taboo alongside sex.

Comment: Lemman, thy grace, and sweete bryd, thyn oore!
The wyndow she undoth, and that in haste.
Have do, quod she, com of, and speed the faste,
Lest that oure neighebores thee espie.
This absolon gan wype his mouth ful drie.
Derk was the nyght as pich, or as the cole,
And at the wyndow out she putte hir hole,
And absolon, hym fil no bet ne wers,
But with his mouth he kiste hir naked ers
Ful savourly, er he were war of this.
Abak he stirte, and thoughte it was amys,
For wel he wiste a womman hath no berd.
He felte a thyng al rough and long yherd,
And seyde, fy! allas! what have I do?

Comment: Darling, my sweetest bird, I wait your will.
The window she unbarred, and that in haste.
Have done, said she, come on, and do it fast,
Before we're seen by any neighbour's eye.
This Absalom did wipe his mouth all dry;
Dark was the night as pitch, aye dark as coal,
And through the window she put out her hole.
And Absalom no better felt nor worse,
But with his mouth he kissed her naked arse
Right greedily, before he knew of this.
Aback he leapt- it seemed somehow amiss,
For well he knew a woman has no beard;
He'd felt a thing all rough and longish haired,
And said, Oh fie, alas! What did I do?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Miller's Tale - Canterbury Tales - Chaucer.  No real bad words in this passage, I just find it funny.

Answer (score 9):

One commonality you'll often find with vulgar words is the presence of fricatives (the *sh* sound, for example) and hard consonants like 'k' and 't'.

You can hear the angry, frustrated release of emotion in words like *fuck* and *shit*, which both share the above characteristics.

Plosive sounds also work well, like the bursting *p* that makes *crap* a fine candidate -- it even feels like you're spitting when you say it.

When people use "minced oaths" as substitutes to the vulgar originals (*fudge* or *shoot*), you'll notice that the hard sounds are noticeably softened (the hard *ck* replaced by the soft *dg* sound, the rough edge of the *t* softened by the long *oo*).

This can be observed in other languages, as well. In German, *scheisse* hisses with its dual fricatives, and the Italian *cazzo* starts off with a hard *k* and grates with its harsh *ts* sound in the middle.

So, from a purely linguistic point of view, words that express someone's pent-up anger with short, sharp bursts of sound make good candidates for swear words.

Comment: I think you may well be right that we favour fricatives & hard consonants in swear words. In words like *fuck, bugger, cunt, bum* we also seem to favour the short ʌ vowel - a sound we often write as *Ugh*, to signify disgust. But I think it's mostly a matter of social conditioning. And phonetic *association*, of course, which is why many Americans today feel uncomfortable with the word *niggardly*.

Comment: And they're called [four-letter words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-letter_word) for a reason.